# Creating ggplot2 with map function from purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I want to make plots of all variables with `ggplot2` using `map` function from `purrr`. Everything is okay except `x-axis label`. Any hint.

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- esoph[ , 1:3]
fm1Plots <- 
  Data %>%
  map(
    ~ ggplot(mapping = aes(x = .)) +
      geom_bar(aes_string(fill = .))  +
      labs(x = .)
  )

fm1Plots[[1]]
```

[image]

```
fm1Plots[[2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over column names in `map`. Note that `aes_string` is deprecated.

```
library(ggplot2)
Data <- esoph[ , 1:3]

fm1Plots <- purrr::map(names(Data), ~ggplot(Data) + 
                                     aes(!!sym(.x), fill = !!sym(.x)) + 
                                     geom_bar()  + labs(x = .x))

fm1Plots[[1]]
```

[image]

You can also use `.data` pronoun

```
fm1Plots <- purrr::map(names(Data), ~ggplot(Data) + 
                    aes(.data[[.x]], fill = .data[[.x]]) + 
                    geom_bar()  + labs(x = .x))
```